# Gparted: cancel pending operation

Tags: partitioning, gparted, live-cd

I started three gparted operations about an hour ago. It consist of moving a partition, growing another and then moving another partition. I would like to cancel the third one / stop after the second. Is this possible? According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/958246) it was already "fixed" in 2013... I already tried right/left/middle clicking the "Applying pending operations" window everywhere, but nothing happened.

Comment: Generally when you cancel an operation in GParted, it will terminate the current operation and all pending operations.  Improved cancel support was added in version 0.15.0 along with asynchronous tracking of progress -- click on **Details** in the [Applying pending operations window](http://gparted.org/screens/gparted_2_big.png) to expand a panel containing a tree structure of operation details.

Comment: But I mean to cancel an upcoming Operation not the current one

Comment: It is currently not possible to cancel future operations without cancelling the currently running operation.

Comment: Too bad :/ this should definitely be included in gparted

Comment: @CurtisGedak:  Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to cancel future operations without cancelling the currently running operation.